# How to vectorize a *given* MATLAB function?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

This might be something silly, but basically, I have a function in MATLAB called `wavedec`. This function does a wavelet decomposition of a vector.

Now, looking at the documentation, the input of this function must be a vector.

However, what if I have a matrix, and I want to call this function for each column of the matrix? Worst case I can put it into a for-loop, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way. (Maybe with arrayfun? I dont know).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using cellfun, you have to convert the matrix to a cell of vectors:

```
mat2cell(M,size(M,1),ones(size(M,2),1))
```

Both, cellfun and arrayfun internally work iterative, which means it's not faster than a for loop.

Comment: Ah interesting. So I might as well just write a for-loop then? Why would MATLAB not vectorize something like that to begin with?

Comment: Excluding some core-functions(multiplication etc) which might get a special treatment by arrayfun/cellfun: It's not possible to run two functions in parallel. What should such a function like cellfun do except calling 'wavedec' iteratively with each input vector?

Comment: No no, what I meant was, why isn't wavedec operable on matricies, like say, fft is? Why would they have designed it like that?

Comment: @Learnaholic: It's not possible to vectorise any function and achieve a speed-up. One reason might be, that the function already uses efficient vectorised operations for a single vector input, then a higher degree of parallelism can't be achieved.